# How to test the given ADT implementation with templates such as <int, int> and <string, int>?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am working on a problem that requires the implementation of two ADT's. After Implementing, I need to test my bag implementations with the following template combinations:

`<int, string>`-- all functions
`<string, int>` -- insert and find functions only

My testing so far has been entering integers to test the different functions. I do not understand what it means to test the implementations with the templates.

Here is my bagADT implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bagADT.h"

template <typename E>
class ABag : public Bag<E> {
private:
int maxSize;
int listSize;
E* listArray;
public:
ABag(int size = defaultSize) { // Constructor
    maxSize = size;
    listSize = 0;
    listArray = new E[maxSize];
}
~ABag() { delete[] listArray; } // Destructor

bool addItem(const E& item) {
    if (listSize >= maxSize) {
        return false;
    }
    listArray[listSize] = item;
    std::cout << "Add Item: Added " << item << " in spot " << listSize << std::endl;
    listSize++;
    return true;
}

bool remove(E& item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        if (listArray[i] == item) {
            std::cout << "Remove: Removed " << item << " from position ";
            item = i;
            std::cout<< item << " and adjusted the location of all other elements." << std::endl;
            for (i= item; i < listSize; i++) {
                listArray[i] = listArray[i + 1];
            }
            listSize--;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool removeTop(E& returnValue) {
    if (listSize == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        returnValue = listArray[listSize - 1];
        std::cout << "Remove Top: Removed " << returnValue << " from the top of the stack." << std::endl;
        for (int i = listSize; i < maxSize; i++) {
            listArray[i] = listArray[i + 1];
        }
        listSize--;
        return true;
    }
}

bool find(E& returnValue) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < (listSize - 1); i++) {
        if (listArray[i] == returnValue) {
            returnValue = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool inspectTop(E& item) const {
    if (listSize == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        item = listArray[listSize - 1];
        std::cout << "Inspect Top: The value on top is currently " << item << "." << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
}

void emptyBag() {
    delete[] listArray;
    listSize = 0;
    listArray = new E[maxSize];
    std::cout << "Empty Bag: Emptied the bag." << std::endl;
}

bool operator+=(const E& addend) {
    if (listSize < maxSize) {

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int size() const {
    std::cout << "Size: Number of elements in listArray: " << listSize << std::endl;
    return (listSize - 1);
}
int bagCapacity() const {
    std::cout << "Bag Capacity: The capacity of this bag is " << maxSize << std::endl;
    return maxSize;
}
};
```

Here is another file provided by my professor called `kvpairs`:

```
#ifndef KVPAIR_H
#define KVPAIR_H

// Container for a key-value pair
// Key object must be an object for which the == operator is defined.
// For example, int and string will work since they both have == defined,
// but Int will not work since it does not have == defined.
template <typename Key, typename E>
class KVpair {
private:
Key k;
E e;
public:
// Constructors
KVpair() {}
KVpair(Key kval, E eval)
{
    k = kval; e = eval;
}
KVpair(const KVpair& o)  // Copy constructor
{
    k = o.k; e = o.e;
}

void operator =(const KVpair& o) // Assignment operator
{
    k = o.k; e = o.e;
}

bool operator==(const KVpair& o) const {
    if (o.k == k) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//The following overload is provided by Adam Morrone, Spring 2016 class.
//Thanks Adam :)
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const KVpair& o) // output print operator 
{
    os << "Key:  " << o.k << "    Value:  " << o.e;
    return os;
}



// Data member access functions
Key key() { return k; }
void setKey(Key ink) { k = ink; }
E value() { return e; }
};


#endif
```

I am expected to show the test outputs using the above templates, but I have no idea how to do this. Also, ignore the += overload. It is incorrect and I know. I am supposed to overload it to directly add a new int to the array.

Comment: I am having trouble providing an answer because we need more information. For example, do they specifically want two template types on the class? Is the `ABag` given to you or did you make it? Why are there two templates? Are you supposed to store both in the bag...?

Comment: @Water `ABag` is the implementation I wrote of the file `bagADT` which was given to me by my professor. It contains pure virtual functions only. I am also given a file called `kvpairs` that I think is only essential to the other ADT I have not started working with yet. I will edit my question and provide the contents of `kvpairs` to see if it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand now. I could be wrong, but this is my guess.

Your bag is singly templated, but it will be holding `KVpair`. They said they will use `KVpair` with `<int, string>` and `<string, int>`.

When they talk about testing it, that means they will be instantiating it as follows:

```
int main() {
    ABag<KVPair<int, string>> bag;
    bag.addItem(KVpair(1, "hi"));
    //...
}
```

This is what I am pretty sure they mean by "testing it with templates".

As a minor edit, I don't know what C++ version you are using but if it's very archaic, you might need to write template instantiation like `ABag<KVPair<int, string> >` instead of putting them together. I remember vaguely this being an issue a long time ago.

Comment: This worked with one small adjustment, on line 3 I had to use: `bag.addItem(KVpair<int,string>(1,"hi"));`